# Get all the post of a specific SUBCATEGORY on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

Hey guys I am trying to get all post of a specific SUBCATEGORY *(No category)*

I'm using the subcategory ID ($option_id) on my code like this:

```
$option_id = get_cat_ID($option);

$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => $option_id,
    // 'category_name' => $option,
    // 'category_in' => $option_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'paged' => $paged
  );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

while( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    $the_query->the_post();

    // Article code here...

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

*This is not working with the subcategories, but is working on categories.*
***Note:*** I have tried using category_name and category_in, I have the same result.

Comment: Your code is correct, and it will work for sub categories also, so the issue is something else. Have you confirmed that `$option` contains a valid category name, and are you sure you have any posts associated with that sub-category?

Comment: Hey FluffyKitten; Yes I have an article posted, I am going to add an image with the values of the option and option_ID vars. Thanks for all help.  

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4hybas5zm7lg5r/Screen%20Shot%202017-10-12%20at%201.54.53%20PM.jpg?dl=0  

https://www.dropbox.com/home/images?preview=Screen+Shot+2017-10-12+at+1.57.03+PM.png

Comment: We can't tell what could be going wrong based on the code you have provided, because it's correct - I even tested it in my own site and it works for sub categories. The problem is with something else. The only other external in the code you posted is `$paged` variable, so unless that is wrong, its impossible to know what it could be without seeing the rest of your code & setup - it could be something in the surrounding code, the posts, filters on WP_Query in functions.php, or a plugin. I'm afraid you'll have to try tracking that down yourself.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thank you very much for all support with this. Let me check step by step if my ajax pagination is working wrong. I will let you know if I find something else.

Comment: I'd suggest going back to basics, and removing as many external influences as possible to rule them out, e.g. remove the pagination from the query altogether, disable all plugins, even try going back to one of the WP default themes and just add this code into it and see if it works then. The more you can rule out, the easier it makes finding the problem :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

@FluffyKitten Hey again, the issues is my pagination *($paged)*

If I remove **'paged' => $paged** I can see articles by subcategory pretty fine.

I need to check my ajax pagination again; thank you very much for the support.